# rename wamp services

Tags: windows-services, wamp

Is there a way to rename the services that are installed with wamp? I tried changing the name of all "wampapache" in wampmanager.ini and wampmanager.conf. That changed the name of the service installed, but then wamp's menus did not recognize the renamed service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give a step by step below. In short, wampmanager.ini does not control the configuration. It is generated by wamp using wampmanager.tpl. There are also a few scripts that should be changed.

For a complete answer, I also list how to *change the port numbers*.

1. run through installer - launch
2. remove services
3. exit wampmanager
4. open wamp/scripts/refresh.php

   1. change all wampapache
   2. change all wampmysqld
5. open wampmanager.conf

   1. change all wampapache
   2. change all wampmysqld
6. open wampmanager.tpl

   1. change all wampapache
   2. change all wampmysqld
7. open uninstall_services.bat

   1. change all wampapache
   2. change all wampmysqld
8. open bin/apache/apache/wampmanager.conf

   1. change all wampapache
9. *open bin/apache/apache/conf/httpd.conf*

   1. *change 80 to <port>*
10. *open wampmanager.tpl*

    1. *change localhost to localhost:<port>*
11. open bin/mysql/mysql<version>/wampmanager.conf

    1. change all wampmysqld
12. open bin/mysql/mysql<version>/my.ini

    1. change 3306 to <port>

start wampserver